# Why can't I pipe to ack?

Tags: grep, ack

So I've been trying to use `grep` to extract some stuff from a Mercurial log and trying to avoid using `awk` just to see if I can get by without it here, and failing because neither `grep` nor `egrep` support full modern regex.

So this happens with grep:

```
$   hg log <filename> | grep changeset
changeset:   3651:d23495ab1168
changeset:   2974:6aa71cb2c575
changeset:   2756:9dd7fb635678
changeset:   2532:d3ced9af4d6c
changeset:   2459:9d5f5553b851
changeset:   1835:4558836beed1
changeset:   1628:517d0239e830
changeset:   1486:114bce51254d
changeset:   1378:2b968e7fbd19
changeset:   1374:4e7772e48d00
```

This is what I want in terms of output results. But to get better regex support, I tried doing this with `ack`, aaaand....nothing. What am I missing? Checked a bunch of examples and can see no difference in what I'm doing here.

```
$  hg log <filename> | ack changeset
$
```

There is no output.

Maybe I am misunderstanding this tool? `egrep` did not have enough support either. I just want to use `\s` :(

Comment: What version of `ack` do you have? You example works fine for me with version 2.14.

Comment: Huh, 1.39. Weird, I just sudo apt-get'd it....why am I out of date...

Comment: What distribution are you using? Even Debian oldstable has 1.92...

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04. Trying to install from [this](https://packages.debian.org/sid/ack-grep) and it is not going well, can't find an actual download link.

Comment: Try downloading it from [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ack-grep) instead...

Comment: Am I supposed to run `source` or `make` on the extracted folder?

Comment: No: on the linked page, click on the little arrow next to "1.92-1" beneath "The Precise Pangolin", then you'll see download links (look for "Package files"). The one you're looking for ends with `_all.deb`; download that and install it with `sudo dpkg -i ack-grep_1.92-1_all.deb`. Before you do that though, `apt-cache policy ack-grep` might help understand what's wrong with your system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22919/discussion-between-aerovistae-and-stephen-kitt).

Answer (score 0):

Saw this on the ack documentation page, maybe it would help?

```
 --[no]filter                  Force ack to treat standard input as a pipe
                            (--filter) or tty (--nofilter)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that (bizarrely) just caused ack to inform me of its version info and basic usage.

Comment: sorry that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try entering

```
awk '/changeset/ {print}'
```

Comment: That only partially works and raises a host of new questions. As you wrote it, it produces the same output as above. But when I adjust the pattern to be `/\s\d+(?=:)/ `(digits followed by a colon and preceded by whitespace) which should match all the same lines, then it gives zero output. Moreover, why can I just write `{print}` rather than `{print(something);} `?

Comment: @temporary_user_name That's because awk only recognizes Extended Regular Expressions (ERE), while \s, \d  and (?= are Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE).

Answer (score 0):

Super late to the party, but with ack v3.3.1 piping works.

```
$ git log | ack 'bar'
```

```
$ ack 'regex' log | ack 'bar'
```

I ran into this because i needed to run a complex regex that i could not do in one line and while under a time crunch.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

If you, by "modern regular expressions", mean Perl-compatible expressions (PCRE), you could always opt for using Perl:

```
hg log something | perl -ne '/pattern/ && print'
```

where `pattern` is your PCRE regular expression.

GNU `grep` supports PCRE if given the `-P` command line option (I don't know how complete the support is though) and GNU `grep` also supports `\s` out of the box as a shorthand for the standard pattern `[[:blank:]]` (matches a tab or a space).  There is also a `pcre2grep` utility, part of the [PCRE2 library](http://www.pcre.org/) package.

Answer (score -1):

`ack` is a default package installed on Debian based distributions. If you see a message like this when you run `ack -h` then you need to use `ack-grep` or follow the step at http://beyondgrep.com/install/ on **Renaming ack-grep on Debian-derived distros**

Try `hg log <filename> | ack-grep changeset` to see if ack-grep is installed properly.